# Unable to store Firebase Storage Image into a folder

Tags: android, android-external-storage

My code is :

```
  String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Cloud_data"+File.separator+"Images";
                file= new File(path);
                if(!file.isDirectory())
                {


                    file.mkdirs();
                }

 storageReference2.getFile(file)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "path"+file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                text1.setText(String.valueOf(file)+"."+taskSnapshot.getStorage());
                                Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "File Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })

.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress=(100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "Progress: "+(int)progress+"%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

I created a folder Cloud_data/image but image are not saving in this folder. How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: Are the folders created? How do you know? You are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). It will return false if it cannot make the directory. You should stop then. Please adapt your code. Also here.

Comment: Folder is creating. but image not coming in folder.Error showing.. 
    FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Cloud_data/Images    and also showing....  E/StorageException: /storage/emulated/0/Cloud_data/Images (Is a directory)

Comment: Where do you see that error/exception?

Comment: I saw these errors in my Logcat and App is working fine but data rae not coming in folder. I just put url of only one image :  storageReference2=storageReference.child("images/hello.jpg");

Comment: When i m giving other path such as cache and package directory then data are coming.

Answer (score 0):

The picture path you used may be used as you would write below.

```
FireabaseStorage firebaseStorage     = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageReference    = firebaseStorage.getReference();
storageReference.child("Cloud_data/"+
            RandomImageName);
    storageReference  .putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
                {
                  Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "path"+file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            text1.setText(String.valueOf(file)+"."+taskSnapshot.getStorage());
                  Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "File Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  

                }

            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
                {
                double progress=(100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                Toast.makeText(DownloadFiles.this, "Progress: "+(int)progress+"%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: I'm not sending data on Cloud. Actually i wanna retrive data in my folder

Answer (score 0):

`File file` is a directory so you cannot use it in `.getFile(file)` as then `file` should point to a file.

Better try `.getFile(new File(file, "myfile.jpg"));`.

Comment: I changed it file to dir but issue is remain same